# Authenticating to Microsoft.Azure.Management.Automation.AutomationManagementClient without using management certificates

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

I'm building a dotnet core 2.1 app and attempting to use AutomationManagementClient to pull status on Azure Automation jobs.

I'm using the constructor of AutomationManagementClient which accepts Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.automation.automationclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Automation_AutomationClient__ctor_Microsoft_Rest_ServiceClientCredentials_System_Net_Http_DelegatingHandler___)

According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.fluent.authentication.azurecredentials?view=azure-dotnet) AzureCredentials is an implementation of Microsoft.Rest.ServiceClientCredentials.

To build the ServiceClientCredentials I use the following code:

```
AuthenticationContext authContext =
                new AuthenticationContext(string.Format
                ("https://login.windows.net/{0}",
                tenantID));

            AuthenticationResult tokenAuthResult =
                authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(applicationId,
                new ClientCredential(applicationId, authenticationKey)).Result;

            TokenCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(tokenAuthResult.AccessToken);

            return new AutomationManagementClient(cred);
```

However on the last line I'm getting the error `cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Rest.TokenCredentials' to 'Microsoft.Azure.SubscriptionCloudCredentials'`

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1. You will be calling the Azure Management API, so the resource you identify in `AcquireTokenAsync` should not be your own app ID, but the identifier for the resource you want a token for: `https://management.azure.com`:

   ```
   AuthenticationResult tokenAuthResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
           "https://management.azure.com",
           new ClientCredential(applicationId, authenticationKey)).Result;
   ```
2. As is mentioned in the error message you cite, the `AutomationManagementClient` constructor expects an instance of `SubscriptionCloudCredentials`, not an instance of `ServiceClientCredentials` (the docs you link to are for `AutomationClient`, not for `AutomationManagementClient`). The closest to what you're trying to do would be `TokenCloudCredentials` (to which you also need to provide the subscription ID):

   ```
   TokenCloudCredentials cred = new TokenCloudCredentials(
           subscriptionId, tokenAuthResult.AccessToken);
   ```